# Multiple index in search result transformation is not working with Kentico

Tags: search, indexing, kentico

I have two different kinds of indexes both are working fine at least in the search preview of my local index.
I added both of them to my smart search part in indexes area, one is a page crawler and the second is a custom index that searches in the media library.
The issue is that the results just match with the results of the crawler and are not showing anything of the custom index.
I think the problem is my smartSearchResults transformation because each time that I try to add a field from the custom index I'm getting an error that the value does not exist. 
my question is how to use both indexes to retrieve all the results in the same web part?

this is  how looks the trasformation

```
   <div class="result">
        <!-- Search result title -->
            <div>
               <a href='<%# SearchResultUrl() %>'>
                    <%#SearchHighlight(HTMLHelper.HTMLEncode(CMS.Base.Web.UI.ControlsHelper.RemoveDynamicControls(DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(Eval("Title"), "/"))), "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>", "</span>")%>
              </a>
            </div>

            <p class="content">
           <%#
            IfCompare(GetSearchValue("UseCustomContent"), true,
              SearchHighlight(LimitLength(HTMLHelper.StripTags(Eval<string>("Content")), 280), "<strong>", "</strong>"),
              SearchHighlight(LimitLength(HTMLHelper.StripTags(GetSearchValue("CustomContent").ToString()), 280), "<strong>", "</strong>")
           )
            %>

          </p><!--  content -->
       <%-- MEDIA LIBRARY CONTENT--%>
      <div>
         <%#GetSearchValue("FileName") %>
      </div>


       <div class="file">
          <i class="<%# GetFileIconClass(Eval<string>("documentExtensions")) %>"></i>
       </div><!--  file -->

            </div>
        </div>
```

But I'm getting no results message

Answer (score 0):

When getting specific field values from a search index you cannot use the simple `Eval("ColumnName")`.  You have to use another method, `GetSearchValue("ColumnName")`.  The `Eval()` method works mainly with the following columns `Title, Content, Image`.  If you're already using the `GetSearchValue()` method then you need to update your question to reflect what you're using or have already tried.

Comment: For to test I just trying to print one of the custom fields in the custom index but yes I've already using GetSearchValue("ColumnName") @Brenden Kehren

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if the value exists before you try to use it. You can use IfEmpty for this. An Example:

```
   <%# IfEmpty(GetSearchValue("Email"),"","<span class='label'>Email</span>")%>  
   <%# IfEmpty(GetSearchValue("Email"),"",GetSearchValue("Email"))%>
```